# regex to match markdown code block

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following string:

```
`example.com` foo bar `baz`
```

That need to be replaced by:

```
<code>example.com</code> foo bar <code>baz</code>
```

So far i'm using following regex:

```
var str = '`example.com` foo bar `baz`'
str.replace(/`(?:(.*$)\n)?([\s\S]*)`/gm, '<code>' + '$2' + '</code>')
```

Results in:

```
"<code>example.com` foo bar `baz</code>"
```

Expected result:

```
"<code>example.com</code> foo bar <code>baz</code>"
```

Comment: Do you also want to be able to escape your backticks? (for example with \\`) Escaping will get tricky (or even impossible) when using regular expressions.

Comment: No, let's keep it simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
var s = '`example.com` foo bar `baz`';
var r = s.replace(/`([^`]+)`/g, '<code>$1</code>');
//=> <code>example.com</code> foo bar <code>baz</code>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you can only use regular expressions, if not trying to implement escape characters, etc.

Here is an example code:

```js
var s = '`example.com` foo bar `baz`';
var r = s.replace(/`(.*?)`/g, '<code>$1</code>');
window.alert("input: "+s+"\nresult: "+r);
```

Please note: The `.*?` matcher will try to find as few characters as possible. It is called **non greedy**.